# jQuery UI sortable - external controls

Tags: jquery-ui, controls, external, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list inside of a modal dialog (non jQuery UI):

```
<div id="modal">
    <ul id="reorderList">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul><!-- /#reorderList -->

    <button class="save" type="button">Save Order</button>
    <button class="cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

I would like to attach a click event handler to the 'Save Order' button that triggers the `sortable('toArray')` functionality. Likewise, I would like the 'Cancel' button to trigger `sortable.('destroy')` to reset the list to it's initial state.

Although I have a good handle on triggering events form within sortable's callback functions, I haven't found any information on calling methods from these external controls.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('.save').click(function(){ 
   reorderListArray = $('#reorderList').sortable('toArray');
});

$('.cancel').click(function(){ 
    $('#reorderList').sortable('cancel');
});
```

This should attach the call to the click event on your save button.  The array is passed into the reorderListArray for you to use as you require.

Hope that helps.